# pad group by table with additional vaules with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

first of: I am not sure this problem is solvable with a sql-query only, but anyhow that is the only solution I can use atm.
I do not want to use another programming language, nor create a new table in my database.
Should this not be possible in pure SQL, that is also an answer I can work with. ;-)

So here goes:

I have a 3 tables consisting of many columns, but I only need one or two from each: orders.orders_no, status.orders_no status.order_status, state.orders_no, state.order_state.

orders_no is numbered from 1-100; status.order_status is status A, status B; and state.order_state is Germany, England, France, USA, India, etc.

What I need is a table that is something like group by, but additionally always shows the number of status for status A, status B, for each state and each order, even if the number of status A or B, for a given state and order is empty.

It would be great if you could help me out! Thank you!

### Example:

Original table with a full outer join across the 3 tables on orders_no

```
order.orders_no | status.order_status | state.order_state
1               | staus a             | DE
1               | staus a             | DE
1               | staus b             | FR
1               | staus b             | DE
2               | staus a             | GB
2               | staus a             | DE
2               | staus b             | DE
2               | staus b             | DE
2               | staus b             | DE
2               | staus b             | FR
3               | staus a             | DE
```

Result after query:

```
order.orders_no | status.order_status | state.order_state| count
1               | staus a             | DE               | 2
1               | staus b             | DE               | 1
1               | staus b             | FR               | 1
1               | staus a             | FR               | 0
2               | staus a             | GB               | 1
2               | staus b             | GB               | 0
2               | staus a             | DE               | 1
2               | staus b             | DE               | 3
2               | staus a             | FR               | 0
2               | staus b             | FR               | 1
3               | staus a             | DE               | 1
3               | staus b             | DE               | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A few self joins do the trick:

```
SELECT x."order", x.status, x.state, count( t.state )
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT "order", t1.status, t2.state
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table1 t2 USING ( "order" )
) x
LEFT JOIN table1 t
ON x."order" = t."order" AND x.status = t.status AND x.state = t.state
GROUP BY x."order", x.status, x.state
ORDER By 1,2,3
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1dd67/21

Comment: Hi kordirko, thanks for the answer. I tried it, but get the error "ERROR:  relation "table1" does not exist". May this be due to the fact, that the data is stored in 3 separate tables?
So rather than x.order, x.status, x.state it is x1.order, x2.status, x3.state